# Spring OAuth 2.0 - Unit Testing OAuth 2.0 client configuration (AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails)

Tags: java, spring, oauth-2.0, spring-oauth2

I am using the spring-oauth 2.0 library to create an OAuth 2.0 client that I can use to obtain and access token from a running OAuth 2.0 authorization server. The client configuration is given below:

```
@Configuration
@EnableOAuth2Client
@PropertySource("classpath:oauth2client.properties")
public class OAuth2ClientConfig {
    @Value("${accessTokenUri}")
    private String accessTokenUri;

    @Value("${userAuthorizationUri}")
    private String userAuthorizationUri;

    @Value("${clientID}")
    private String clientID;

    @Value("${clientSecret}")
    private String clientSecret;

    @Bean
    public OAuth2ProtectedResourceDetails oauth2Client() {
        AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails details = new AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails();
        details.setId("oauth2client");
        details.setClientId(clientID);
        details.setClientSecret(clientSecret);
        details.setAccessTokenUri(accessTokenUri);
        details.setUserAuthorizationUri(userAuthorizationUri);
        details.setTokenName("access_token");
        details.setScope(Arrays.asList(new String[] { "email", "cn" }));
        details.setPreEstablishedRedirectUri("http://oauth2callback/");
        details.setUseCurrentUri(false);
        return details;
    }

    @Bean
    public OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2ClientRestTemplate(OAuth2ClientContext clientContext) {
        OAuth2RestTemplate oAuth2RestTemplate = new OAuth2RestTemplate(oauth2Client(), clientContext);
        AccessTokenProvider accessTokenProvider = new AccessTokenProviderChain(Arrays.<AccessTokenProvider> asList(
                new AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider(), new ImplicitAccessTokenProvider(),
                new ResourceOwnerPasswordAccessTokenProvider(), new ClientCredentialsAccessTokenProvider()));
        oAuth2RestTemplate.setAccessTokenProvider(accessTokenProvider);
        return oAuth2RestTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public static PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        return new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
    }
}
```

Now, I am trying to unit test this configuration. The unit test is given below:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = OAuth2ClientConfigTestConfig.class)
@OAuth2ContextConfiguration(AuthorizationCodeResourceDetails.class)
public class OAuth2ClientConfigTest implements RestTemplateHolder {

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2ClientConfig oauth2ClientConfig;

    @Autowired
    private OAuth2RestTemplate oauth2RestTemplate;

    @Rule
    public OAuth2ContextSetup context = OAuth2ContextSetup.withEnvironment(this, new MockEnvironment());

    @BeforeClass
    public static void setup() {
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    @Test
    public void testOAuth2Client() throws Exception {
        System.out.println(oauth2ClientConfig);
        OAuth2AccessToken accessToken = oauth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken();
        System.out.println(accessToken);
    }

    @Override
    public void setRestTemplate(RestOperations restTemplate) {
        restTemplate = this.oauth2RestTemplate;
    }

    @Override
    public RestOperations getRestTemplate() {
        return oauth2RestTemplate;
    }

}
```

However, when I run the test, I get an exception:

```
org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.UserRedirectRequiredException: A redirect is required to get the users approval
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.getRedirectForAuthorization(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:359)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.grant.code.AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.obtainAccessToken(AuthorizationCodeAccessTokenProvider.java:205)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainNewAccessTokenInternal(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:142)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.token.AccessTokenProviderChain.obtainAccessToken(AccessTokenProviderChain.java:118)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.acquireAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:221)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.OAuth2RestTemplate.getAccessToken(OAuth2RestTemplate.java:173)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.test.OAuth2ContextSetup.getAccessToken(OAuth2ContextSetup.java:243)
    at org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.test.OAuth2ContextSetup.starting(OAuth2ContextSetup.java:200)
    at org.junit.rules.TestWatchman$1.evaluate(TestWatchman.java:51)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:254)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:89)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:193)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
```

Is there any way I get get to test the OAuth 2.0 client which is using the "authorization_code" grant type?

Comment: Ever solve this?